# kextstat-Listed Files Not Present in Extensions Folder

Tags: macos, kernel-extensions

I used "kextstat | grep -v com.apple" to find active extensions, and found the following listed extensions.

```
  119    3 0xffffff7f826c7000 0x3e000    0x3e000    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (3.2.4) <7 5 4 3 1>
  121    0 0xffffff7f8196c000 0x8000     0x8000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (3.2.4) <119 35 28 7 5 4 3 1>
```

I want to unload them with kextunload in order to reduce kernel memory usage, but there are not any org.virtualbox.kext.* files present in my /System/Library/Extensions/ directory. Any suggestions on how I can find where these are being stored and unload them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox puts their kexts into `/Library/Extensions` just as they should be. No third party should put anything into `/System…` if it's not absolutely necessary to do so.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. (Duh!) I checked /Users/me/Library but not /Library. Found 'em.